# $\int_X fd\mu$, when $\mu$ is finitely-additive (and not countably additive)

Tags: measure-theory

If $X$ is a space, $F\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on this space and $\mu$ is a **finitely-additive** (and not necessarily countably additive) measure on $F$, then is there a standard way to define the integral $\int_X fd\mu$?

Comment: A standard way exists when $f$ is a simple function, or the uniform limit of simple functions.  When discussing finitely additive measures, often they are defined only on an algebra, not a sigma-algebra.